# Python Selenium Dynamic Xpath combined with grid reference

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use Selenium to pull a value from a grid within a dynamic element.  The grid reference remains constant though.

The xpath is:

//*[@id="mat-tab-content-2-0"]/div/div/div/div[1]/mat-card[3]/mat-card-content/usq-user-rankings/div/div/div/mat-card/mat-table/mat-row[1]/mat-cell[4]

The 'content-2' and the 'mat-card[3]' are dynamic.  The text 'user-rankings' appears to be persistent though.  I am trying to create an xpath expression that can find the element containing the grid using the 'user-rankings' text and include the grid reference or row1 and column 4.

Any suggestions on syntax?

Comment: What is the site you are working on? Anyway, `//usq-user-rankings/div/div/div/mat-card/mat-table/mat-row[1]/mat-cell[4]` should work, give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately, that still yields the following error when used in the following statement:

ratingvalue = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//usq-user-rankings/div/div/div/mat-card/mat-table/mat-row[1]/mat-cell[4]')).text

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//usq-user-rankings/div/div/div/mat-card/mat-table/mat-row[1]/mat-cell[4]"}

The table itself is behind a login/pw authentication, so hard to share.

Comment: Please share a url to the source OR at least share some source HTML.